# Phonegap jQuery ajax getting unauthorized only on Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova, basic-authentication

I'm working on a Phonegap application that is sending POST data to a server. The code works on iOS, Nexus 5 running Android 4.4.4 and on different browsers on desktop. I am, however, getting Unauthorized, http basic auth on NodeJS, on our target device Galaxy Trend Plus running Android 4.2.2 as well as on emulators with Android 4.2.2, 4.3 and 4.4.2.

-Phonegap version 3.5.0-0.21.014 
-jquery-1.10.2.min.js 
-jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js

The code sending the data, this is triggered from a button at this point

```
function sendData(){
  var url = 'http://somethingsomething.com/addData'

  var msg=  {
    'userID':localStorage.getItem('id'),
    'userName':localStorage.getItem('name'),
    'log':localStorage.getItem('log') 
  };


  var result = $('#result');
  result.html('POST to: ' + url)
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(msg),
    username: 'asdf',
    password: 'asdf',
    xhrFields:{withCredentials: true},
    contentType: 'application/json',
    satusCode:{ 200: function(){  result.html('POST success!') } },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { result.html('Success : ' + data) },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { result.html('Error: '+     jqXHR.readyState + ' ' + errorThrown); }
  });

}
```

The headers that work and are sent from browser and Nexus are the same:

```
Request URL:http://asdf:asdf@somethingsomething.com/addData
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.
Accept:*/*
Content-Type:application/json
Origin:file://
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; Nexus 5 Build/KTU84P) AppleWebKit/537.36     (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/33.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
Request Payloadview source
{userID:57, userName:NEXUS,…}
log: "...deleted..."
userID: "57"
userName: "NEXUS"

Response Headers
Accept-Ranges:none
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/plain
Date:Mon, 20 Oct 2014 08:10:59 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=99
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:Express
```

I know that everything works, the data is getting sent and saved on the server. The issue is only with the Galaxy TrendPlus running android 4.2.2. Chromes inspect device doesn't work with it so I really have no way to debug it. Other than maybe piping the traffic through my computer (Ubuntu) and monitoring that?

Any and all help/ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

ADDED:
Any differences that I can think of should be related to the browser that is used so I checked navigator.userAgent
Trend Plus:          Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/534.30 Safari/534.30
Nexus 5:             Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 Chrome/37.000 Mobile Safari/537.36
Chromium on ubuntu:  Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 Ubuntu Chromium(37.0.2062.120 Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36

ADDED:
Okay, I ran the code in the Android Eclipse SDK and got this from LogCat on the Trend running Android 4.2.2 when trying to send the data. The Nexus doesn't seem to output anything to LogCat.

```
external/chromium/net/socket/ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc:300: [1021/132507:INFO:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(300)] [cac_debug_log][ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc] GetInstance() cac_sata_: 0 CAC_CONTEXT_CAC: 3

external/chromium/net/socket/ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc:[1021/132507:INFO:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(10)] ssl_ctx_ is used

external/chromium/net/socket/ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc:[1021/132507:INFO:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(512)] ~SSLClientSocketOpenSSL()
```

To clarify: the connection is over SSL and the POST must be verified with httpBasicAuth. Haven't got a clue about what those messages mean. Google takes me to https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=166746 these types of pages which are not helping.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have a similar AJAX error that inexplicably only occurs on mobile platforms...